# Один из восьми тестов не проходит, не могу посмотреть какой. Что в коде может выдавать неверный результат? Задача на работу с последовательностями

Tags: python-3.x, if, while

**Задача**
Вам подаётся последовательность натуральных чисел, оканчивающихся нулём (нуль в саму последовательность не входит). Необходимо найти сумму подпоследовательности, состоящую из элементов, для которых предыдущий элемент исходной последовательности является нечётным.

*Формат входных данных:*
Последовательность произвольной длины, состоящая из натуральных чисел и оканчивающаяся нулём.

*Формат выходных данных:*
Число: -1, если длина исходной последовательности строго меньше 2; -1, если подпоследовательность пустая; в остальных случаях - сумма элементов подпоследовательности.

**Код**

```
number = int(input())
len = 0
sum = 0

while number != 0:
    len += 1
    if number % 2 == 1:
        number = int(input())
        sum += number
    else:
        number = int(input())
if len < 2:
    print(-1)
else:
    print(sum)
```

Comment: 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 ?

Comment: Я не понял, что нужно найти. Подпоследовательность это часть исходной последовательности без пропусков, а нк просто набор чисел из исходной последовательности.

Comment: `len` и `sum` - встроенные функции питона, не используйте их в качестве имён переменных, это так, на будущее